# Xcode: UITableViewCell customization like Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm working on this UITableViewCell customization and i've try a L O T of things. I've used subviews, i've used drawrect, I've used both, but everytime i can't get a smooth scrolling. Let me add something else: even Facebook news feed not scrolling so smooth, but i see some apps (like GetGlue) that has custom cell (some with text, some with images) and scroll incredibly smooth.

I'm just asking if there is a method that can help me to get the best result.

NOTE: Images are downloaded using SDWEBIMAGE.

here is some code (this is the drawrect method for a subview of uitableviewcell):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Ottengo il contenuto grafico
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();// Background
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, self.frame.size.height - 15), NULL);
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 3.5, [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2].CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode (context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
    CGPathRelease(path);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // Rettangolo per Social Button
    UIImage *socialRectImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"activitySocialBarBackground"];
    CGRect socialRect = CGRectMake(10, self.frame.size.height - 35 - 5, 300, 35);
    CGPathRef socialBarPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(socialRect, NULL);
    CGContextAddPath(context, socialBarPath);
    [socialRectImage drawInRect:socialRect];
    CGPathRelease(socialBarPath);

    //###### Immagine

    // Actor Image
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(18, 18, 40, 40);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGPathRef clippath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageRect cornerRadius:20].CGPath;
    CGContextAddPath(context, clippath);
    CGContextClip(context);
    [[activityArray objectForKey:@"actorImage"] drawInRect:imageRect];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    // Actor DisplayName
    CGPoint point;
    NSDictionary *mainTextAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:13.5f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:130.0f/255.0f green:27.0f/255.0f blue:67.0f/255.0f alpha:1] };
    NSAttributedString *localeNameAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:activity.actor.displayName attributes:mainTextAttributes];
    point = CGPointMake(66, 23);
    [localeNameAttributedString drawAtPoint:point];

    // Activity Time Type
    NSDictionary *TimeTypeTextAttributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor grayColor] };
    NSAttributedString *TimeTypeAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[activityArray objectForKey:@"activityTimeType"] attributes:TimeTypeTextAttributes];
    point = CGPointMake(66, 40);
    [TimeTypeAttributedString drawAtPoint:point];

    // Activity Message
    CGSize ActivityMessageTextSize = [activity.shortMessage sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 100) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGRect newTextFrame = CGRectInset(CGRectMake(18, 68, 280, 100), 0, 0);
    [activity.shortMessage drawInRect:newTextFrame withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f] lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];


    // Object Image
    if ( [imagesDownload objectForKey:@"objectImage"] != nil ) {
        CGRect objectImageRect = ( activity.object.image.url != nil ) ? CGRectMake(0, 68 + ActivityMessageTextSize.height, 300, 168) : CGRectMake(-5, 68 + ActivityMessageTextSize.height, 310, 310);
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        clippath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:objectImageRect cornerRadius:0].CGPath;
        CGContextAddPath(context, clippath);
        CGContextClip(context);
        //[[imagesDownload objectForKey:@"objectImage"] drawInRect:objectImageRect];
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }


}
```

PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

----ITALIAN-----

Ciao, io ho appena creato un social network che si chiama **startMe**.
E' molto molto simile al tuo per quanto riguarda la grafica e l'organizzazione.
La differenza è che tu stai disegnando la cella da codice, e questo ASSOLUTAMENTE non va bene.

**Devi creare dei nib file con le tue celle già disegnate**, e semplicemente poi gestirne i contenuti e l'altezza. L'altezza in particolare, devi calcolarla una sola volta nel metodo del delegato delle tabelle apposito *heightForCellAtIndexPath* o qualcosa di simile ;)

Il mio progetto è in vendita e devo dire che scorre senza intoppi, puoi anche guardare il video su youtube.

;)

-----ENGLISH-----

Hello, I have just created a social network called **startMe** .
It 'very very similar to your regarding the graphics and the organization.
The difference is that you are drawing the cell code, and this ABSOLUTELY no good.

**You have to create files with your cells already drawn**, and then simply manage the content and height. The height, in particular, you have to calculate it only once in the method of the delegate tables heightForCellAtIndexPath or something like that;)

My project is on sale and I must say it runs smoothly, you can also watch the video on youtube.

;)

[image]

----ITALIAN----

Ho anche visto che disegni molte cose con il core graphics e questo rallenta molto il tutto.
E' molto più semplice se agisci sulle proprietà del layer delle immagini. Di seguito posto una mia classe che ho usato per fare le immagini tonde come hai fatto tu:

----ENGLISH----

I also saw that designs many things with the graphics core and this slows the whole thing.
It 'very easy if you act on the properties of the layer images. Following a place in my class that I used to make the images round like you did:

.h

```
//
//  RoundCornerImage.h
//  startMe
//
//  Created by Matteo Gobbi on 24/08/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Matteo Gobbi. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RoundCornerImageView : UIImageView

-(void)setBorderWidth:(float)width;
-(void)setCornerRadius:(float)radius;
-(void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)color;
-(void)setCircleMask;

@end
```

.m

```
//
//  RoundCornerImage.m
//  startMe
//
//  Created by Matteo Gobbi on 24/08/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Matteo Gobbi. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RoundCornerImageView.h"

@implementation RoundCornerImageView

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    CALayer * l = [self layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:10.0];

    // You can even add a border
    [l setBorderWidth:self.frame.size.width/IMG_PROFILE_BORDER_SCALE];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];
}

-(void)setBorderWidth:(float)width {
    [[self layer] setBorderWidth:width];
}

-(void)setCornerRadius:(float)radius {
    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:radius];
}

-(void)setBorderColor:(UIColor *)color {
    [[self layer] setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];
}


-(void)setCircleMask {
    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:self.frame.size.width/2.0];
}

@end
```

----ITALIAN----

Questa semplicemente estende la classe UIImageView, ti basta impostarla sull'oggetto imageView che hai su interface builder. Dal codice poi, nel metodo che gestisce le celle delle tabelle, puoi richiamare i metodi della classe per settare bordi e colori se ce ne fosse bisogno. O puoi modificarti la classe affinchè di default utilizzi le caratteristiche che ti interessano.

Spero di esserti stato utile ;)

----ENGLISH----

This simply extends the UIImageView class, you just set it on the object you have on imageView interface builder. Since then the code in the method that handles the table cells, you can call the methods of the class to set borders and colors if it were needed. Or you can modificarti class for default uses the features that interest you.

Hope that useful;)

Comment: Auw. Do un'occhiata. Devo dire che l'opzione di utilizzare i nib non l'ho neanche considerata. Grazie Matteo!

Comment: E' davvero molto importante credimi, meno codice scrivi e meno operazioni di disegno devi fare e meglio è. Ho appena editato il codice e ti ho posato qualcosa di utile ;) Devi praticamente rimuovere tutto il codice che hai in drawRect e fare tutto da nib o xib e qualcosa dal metodo cellForRowAtIndexPath o simili. Ho aggiunto anche un immagine di una mia cella.

Comment: Grazie Matteo, sto anche dando un'occhiata ai tuoi lavori. Mi sono affacciato da un mesetto alla programmazione objective-c, è entusiasmante e logorante, ma va bene così. Grazie ancora, provo un po' tutto quello che mi hai consigliato e vediamo.

Comment: Se tutto ciò ti è utile, ti prego di segnalare la risposta come corretta ;)
Inoltre se mi dai un tuo contatto, vorrei fare due chiacchiere. I miei contatti li trovi su matteogobbi.it

Comment: Assolutamente, è quello che farò. Provveduto con Facebook per il contatto!

Comment: ok ;)
Per segnalare la risposta devi spuntare la V verde appena sotto le freccette dove prima hai fatto l'up vote ;) Grazie, ci tengo ad aiutare!

Comment: PS: Comunque avevo iniziato a utilizzare il drawrect in funzione di questo: https://blog.twitter.com/2012/simple-strategies-smooth-animation-iphone

Comment: si in realtà puoi usare il drawRect (anche se ti fai un gran culo), ma su quel post viene spiegato anche di avere parecchi accorgimenti. In realtà la cosa migliore sarebbe usare i nib che vengono disegnati in automatico. Poi cose particolari se ce n'è bisogno le fai dal drawrect ;)